# Discord js .. 8ball isn't producing random results

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have one problem with my `Discord` bot

It seems that my script is not producing random results.
It worked before I put it in `embed`

```
function doanswer() {
    var answers = ["Yes", "No", Maybe ]
    return answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];
}

var otazka = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor(0x88f9ed)
  .addField("Answer", ("your answer is: " + doanswer()));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Maybe` be a string?

Comment: If you're script "is not producing random results", what is it producing? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than placing your answer in an embed you could just do:

````
"```" + "Answer \n" + "your answer is: " + doanswer() + "```"
````

You probably won't get your custom colour, unless there is a way I don't know about, but this will look nice regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function doanswer() {
    var answers = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe" ]
    i = Math.floor(math.random()*answers.length);
    return answers[i];
}

var otazka = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor(0x88f9ed)
  .addField("Answer", ("your answer is: " + doanswer()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have 2 problems with your code:

1. You need to have " or ' around every single value inside of the array. This means this first block of code should look like:

   ```
   function doanswer() {
       var answers = ["Yes","No","Maybe"]
       return answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)];
   }
   ```
2. `answers.length` is probably going to result in you getting the answer of undefined a lot. This is because you array only contains 3 values. If the length of the input answer (`answers.length`) is more than 2 then the randomizer might get a number such as 5. If the randomizer asks for 5 put there isn't a value in the answers = ['Yes','No','Maybe'] then the code automatically assigns it as undefined.

Summary/Tips: Cover your values with " or ' and also don't put numbers in a randomizer bigger than the value of the array, define variables/arrays outside of functions, var can be replaced with either var or const (https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75 for more information)

I recommend you change your code to:

```
function doAnswer() {
    var answers = ['Yes','No','Maybe'];
    message.reply(answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)]);
}
```